# User registration and signup using private and public key

Tags: android, react-native, security

I am trying to create a react native app where users can log in without using passwords or emails. The idea is that at registration, we capture users cellphone number, verify it using OTP and once verified we create a RSA public/private key pair. The private key stays on the users phone while the public key is sent to the backend (using HTTPS API). All content going forward, is encrypted using private/public keys.

To log in and identify the user in future, we basically use the cellphone number + public key.

My question is purely from a security perspective - is the above method safe in absence of a regular username/password type scenario? Are there any drawbacks to using this approach?

Are there any frameworks/apps that already use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a few things to consider:

How is the private key stored and what happens if the app data is cleared or the app is installed?  This could freeze a user out if the private key is lost.

What if someone changes their phone number?  Is tying it to a phone number meaningful at that point if all they need is the private key to update it?

If the private key is lost and all you need is the phone number to regenerate it, it's not hard to envision a scenario where a phone number is compromised and then the account is impersonated.

Keys by themselves have no way to be revoked other than marking the public key as bad in your system.  Every endpoint the phone is talking to that needs to encrypt or verify data would need to be aware of this if marking keys as compromised is a feature.

Probably obvious, but if there's no additional password on the app, anyone who has access to the phone has access to the channel.